# What is a "dear grandma, love egg" moment?

Tags: idioms, british-english

Robert Peston [recently wrote on his BBC blog](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/business-24346376):

> But it would mean that the perceived quality of all the trillions of dollars of bonds it has sold would deteriorate (here is one of my "dear grandma, love egg" moments - when a government issues a bond, it is borrowing from investors).

What on earth is a “dear grandma, love egg” moment?

Comment: 'Teaching your grandmother to suck eggs' is a British idiom for unnecessary advice: I presume it's connected, but can't see exactly how.

Comment: @TimLymington: I'd rather speculate on something in that general area than start thinking about grandmas in conjunction with what we usually understand by [love egg!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Love_egg)

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I think this is a letter-ending “Much love (from), Egg” kind of love egg more than the vibrating kind. It seems almost as if the egg your nana has sucked is now writing letters to her from beyond the ovosuction grave … or something like that.

Comment: @Janus: All three of *my*  (maternal, paternal, and a "by adoption") nanas have passed on, but I think at some point they'd all have told me not to teach them to suck eggs. And I'm absolutely *certain* none of them would ever have signed off a letter "from Egg". Not that I ever saw any of them actually *suck* eggs in the first place, but I don't see why that should lead to them actually *becoming* eggs (unless you're thinking along the lines of "You are what you eat" :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I think you misunderstood me. I meant the entire quoted phrase looks like the opening and the ending to a hypothetical letter send to grandma from the (sucked?) egg: “Dear grandma, [content here]. Love, Egg”.

Comment: @Janus: oic. Well, no I don't, actually. In OP's specific context, why would the writer refer to himself as "Egg"? I've never heard of such a usage, and it would seem more likely he'd write something like "dear grandma, love Bobby" if that was the sense intended.

Comment: ...whatever - I'm closevoting as POB on the grounds that this isn't a standard usage, so it's all idle speculation. There are currently only three instances of "dear grandma, love egg" indexed on Google. One is this actual question, the other two are citing the same BBC blog post being asked about here.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I agree that this isn't standard usage, but there's no need for speculation either. It's a clear allusion to some remarks he'd made in another recent article, which regular readers would presumably recognize.

Comment: And in context, I would agree that it means “Dear Grandma – Sincerely, Eggs.” With the eggs from the previous article being anthropomorphized.

Comment: I cannot for the life of me understand why *anyone* would think this is On Topic here.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a NARQ.

Comment: In the old scheme of things, this would probably be **Too Localized.** I don't see how it's **Not a Real Question,** and having found a single, clear answer I'd say it's certainly not **Primarily Opinion-Based.** Ultimately, the problem is that the meaning is unique to the author and not general English, but there's no way for the original poster to know that without having first found the meaning.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about idiosyncratic usage of a single author and not a general English idiom.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This cryptic metaphor appears to be an allusion to two asides that the author made in another article just a few days before the one quoted. From [“Has Labour fallen out of love with business?”](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/business-24281780):

> (everything else being equal, the cost of capital rises as shares fall - sorry for the eggs tutorial, Grandma)
>
> (Here's more eggs stuff, Grandma - when it becomes more expensive to raise capital, it becomes more expensive to invest in big projects).

The essence of the metaphor is that mentioning these basic economic principles to his audience is like lecturing his grandmother about eggs. It's a playful form of preaching to the choir.

Comment: Downvoter: Any suggestion for improvement here?